# iOS UI automated tests: reusing app-data between devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

I am writing an iOS app and I started adding UI automated tests. I am using *xcode7.1.1*.

As the app relies heavily on data and a logged-in user - I want to create an app-data package and reuse it when running the tests, so when a test starts - there is already a logged-in user with some data in the app.

I followed this guide:
http://corporationunknown.com/blog/2014/07/10/preloading-development-data-into-your-ios-app/
And it works perfectly fine when I:

1. Install the app on a real device (iPhone), play with it and download the app-data to a file
2. Add the file to my project and execute my tests using that app-data - on the same real device

Ideally I would be able to:

1. Create the app-data form a simulator instead of a real device
2. Be able to use the app-data on any device, ideally a simulator

See, the thing is that for other team members to add UI tests - it would be best if we can simulate some scenario, save the app-data, include it in the project and allow anyone to use it on any device (real or simulator).

I tried running the app with the app-data (again - generated on a real device) on a simulator with no success. It is simply **ignored** and the app starts empty.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to run an app with a pre-loaded app-data created from a different device?
   If yes - how?
   Does it require editing the contents of the package?
2. Is it possible to create an app-data package from a simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might provide you some more information on it's current state, https://github.com/lionheart/openradar-mirror/issues/6578

Comment: Thanks @Sushant. Marked as answered.
Hopefully we see Apple's courtesy and have it fixed soon.